# Getting position of UIImageView in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, position

Hey I made a project where multiple UIImageView is randomly created and all of them moves up the screen by NSTimer.

Is there any way to detect the current position of the moving UIImageView?

The moving image is a balloon and I want to "pop" or more like remove the UIImageView when the User taps any of the balloons.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the frame property of the UIImageView.

```
if(xValue>CGRectGetMinX(balloon.frame) && xValue<CGRectGetMaxX(balloon.frame) &&
yValue>CGRectGetMinY(balloon.frame) && yValue<CGRectGetMaxY(balloon.frame)) {
  //pop the balloon
}
```